# Change certificate MS Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, exchange-2013

I need to change the certificate in an Exchange environment with several servers. The certificate has not yet expired. I use the same certificate for SMTP, IMAP, POP, IIS etc and a send connector towards Office 365.

In this setup I have 3 questions:

1. When I change the send connector certificate, does it change it for
   all servers or only the one connected to in PowerShell?
2. If it only change the send connector on one server, will the communication work
   for all the other servers towards O365 with the old certificate?
3. If I change the SMTP,IMAP, POP, IIS certificate on one server, but not
   the others. Will it still work like normal?

I just want to be sure that I update the certificate on all the correct places and having minimum / no downtime if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you configure certificate for connectors before? You could get this information first then change the certificate if necessary. You need change it for the connector one by one. Not all connectors need to configure certificate.
2. Is it hybrid deployment? I check in my lab, only Default Frontend connector is configured certificate, if the old certificate is still working, you could use it.
3. It depends on whether the certificate is healthy. But we didn’t suggest do this. May I know why you want to do this?
   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f48cca34-21c0-4298-a0c2-ef41d9b64e55/exchange-2016-with-multiple-certificates-for-popimapsmtpiis?forum=Exch2016Adm

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers

Comment: The questions helped and pointed me in the correct direction. Thank you!